# Changing velocity of object in Java Game

Tags: java

So I'm making a sort of space game in Java. Currently, the spacecraft stays in place if the user isn't doing anything, and moves at a constant velocity in different directions based on the user's key input.

I'd like to change it so that when the spacecraft is moving, as the user continues to press the key, the spacecraft's velocity accelerates faster.

In my move method, I currently have

```
public void move() {
    x += dx;
    y += dy;
}
```

I've tried doing such things as

```
public void move() {
    x *= dx;
    y *= dy;
}
```

But constantly multiplying values makes the spacecraft move way too fast.

Is there another approach to doing this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might want to look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/667034/simple-physics-based-movement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need to change `dx` according to a keyboard event of your choice.  So:

- Write a [listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6885545/keyboard-actionlistener) to capture keypresses
- Test the key to see if it's the one you want (up arrow, down arrow, etc)
- Increment/decrement `dx` (testing for min/max values) accordingly.  You could do some fun physics formula here based on the current value of `dx`?

Then, when the spaceship `move`s, `dx` will be either large, or small, depending on how many times the user has pounded on the key.

Comment: Yeah, this site is the biggest resource anyone could ask for in the software dev world.